# [objective-c]How do I send one method a message from another .m file

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5

I am trying to take a picture from my iPad app, using code I have found on the internet.  I have this method:

```
- (BOOL) startCameraControllerFromViewController: (UIViewController*) controller
                                   usingDelegate: (id <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,
                                                   UINavigationControllerDelegate>) delegate {
```

in a file called CameraViewController.m.

In CameraViewController.h, I have this definition:

```
@interface CameraViewController : UIViewController

+ (BOOL) startCameraControllerFromViewController: (UIViewController*) controller
                                   usingDelegate: (id <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,
                                   UINavigationControllerDelegate>) delegate;

@end
```

I am trying to call it from this method which is in ClientSetupViewController.m:

```
    - (void) captureImage  {

        [startCameraControllerFromViewController: self usingDelegate: self];
}
```

I'm getting an error saying

> Use of undeclared identifier startCameraControllerFromViewController

I have #import "CameraViewController.h" in CLientViewController.h

I'm totall lost!  I thought I had everything defined correctly, but I guess not.  What is wrong with my code?

UPDATE:  getting this error now after changing code to call instance:

> Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CameraViewController", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in ClientSetupViewController.o
>         anon in CameraViewController.o
>         l_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_CameraViewController_$_CameraDelegateMethods in CameraViewController.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture
>   armv7 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to
>   see invocation)

Comment: In `CameraViewController.h` you have the function declared as a class function. In the .m file, you have it declared as an instance function. Is this typo in your original code?

Comment: The sorry state of iOS development... Man, please at least make the effort to learn the language before diving deep into making an app... You and your users are going to have a lot of headache if you continue doing this...

Comment: No, not a typo... I hate to ask this lame question, but what's it supposed to be?  (I need to read up on the difference between instance methods and the other type)

Comment: They are either both `-` or both `+`. It's a class function (called on the class itself) or an instance function (called on an existing instance of the class).

Comment: wardd:  there is no class... so I guess they are both instance methods... let me change it and see if that helps...  UPDATE:  I changed both to -, and it makes no difference... still getting the error.

Comment: @spokane-dude I'm sorry if I hurt you - I didn't mean to do so, and all this is not about "being bright"... I just wanted to point out my *opinion* about what you should do.

Comment: `startCameraControllerFromViewController` is a function from the class `CameraViewController`. You have to decide whether or not this function is called on the class itself (`[CameraViewController startCameraControllerFromViewController:self usingDelegate:self]`), or called on an instance of the class: `CameraViewController * c = [[CameraViewController alloc] init];`, `[c startCameraControllerFromViewController:self usingDelegate:self];`

Comment: Do either of your know which doc explains this?  Obviously, I need to do some reading... I'll try that and get back to you...

Comment: So let me ask one more Q:  if I have a Controller, is it considered a class even tho there is no "class" word per se?

Comment: @spokane-dude Yes, it is - anything that you declare using `@interface` is a class. Also, here's a pretty good language tutorial which explains all the basics in detail: http://www.otierney.net/objective-c.html

Comment: Anything with `@interface` declares a class. `@implementation` defines everything that you declared in the `@interface`. Check out articles here to get started https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Getting%20Started.

Comment: H2CO3: thank you... wasn't aware (or forgot) about @interface.

Comment: wardd:  it apparently is calling on an instance of the class, but I'm now getting this error (see UPDATE to original question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `startCameraControllerFromViewController:usingDelegate:` is indeed a class function (as indicated by the +), then the way to call the function would be:

`[CameraViewController startCameraControllerFromViewController: self usingDelegate: self]`

A message is sent to an object, or a class. In your code, you have just the message name in the message call `[  ]`, with no indication of where this message should be sent to.

Comment: Thank you... I'll spend some time looking at the docs and see if I can figure the rest out myself.  I appreciate the help...

Answer (score 3):

Please go through an Objective-C tutorial once more before making *The Best iOS App Ever (TM)* - you're missing **fundamentals** of the syntax.

One, you're using the `-` and `+` method prefixes inconsistently. Decide whether it should be a class (`+`) or instance (`-`) method and add the prefix accordingly - and use the same prefix both in the declaration in the header file **and** in the definition (in the implementation file).

Once you have fixed this, you have to send the message to **the class itself** if you defined a class method or **to an instance** if you have an instance method. Example using a class method:

```
[CameraViewController startCameraControllerFromViewController:self usingDelegate:self];
```

Example using an instance method:

```
[someOtherViewController startCameraControllerFromViewController:self usingDelegate:self];
```

assuming that `someOtherViewController` is a valid instance of `CameraViewController`.

Comment: Got it... thank you... I appreciate the help.. :D  As an aside: If I check on the checkmark and mark your answer as correct, what is the protocol when two people are correct and gave the help?  Is the checkmark different than the "up vote"?

Comment: @spokane-dude the checkmark is different - you should accept the answer that you found the most useful, since only one answer can be accepted. You can, however, upvote any answers that you found helpful. Also note that while up (and down-) votes are locked in after 5 minutes, you can always accept *another* answer (in case they changed in the meantime).

Comment: I feel you both gave excellent answers... do you guys get points for the answwer or the up and down votes?

Comment: @spokane-dude yes - an upvote means +10, a downvote -2 points, an accept is worth +15.

Comment: Aww geeze... now I have to make a decision... I hate that!  which one of you wants/needs the points the most?

Comment: @spokane-dude wardd needs them :) (I've already hit the daily limit of 200, so let I not be nitpicky about this :P)